# segmentio/kafka-go Offset Output out of range: requested offset is outside the range offsets maintained by the server for the given topic\partition

Tags: go, apache-kafka, segment-io

I use segmentio/kafka-go (v0.4.40) to work with kafka.

```
    reader := kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
        Brokers:   []string{broker},
        GroupTopics:     []string{topic},
        GroupID: "group",
        MinBytes: cfg.MinBytes,
        MaxBytes: cfg.MaxBytes,
        QueueCapacity: cfg.QueueCapacity,
        SessionTimeout: cfg.SessionTimeout, 
        MaxAttempts: cfg.MaxAttempts,        
        Logger:    kafka.LoggerFunc(log.New(log.Writer(), "[kafka reader] ", 0).Printf),
    })
```

While the application was running, the directories where the topic data is stored were cleared. Errors appeared in the logs:
`error initializing the Kafka reader for partition. Offset Output out of range: requested offset is outside the range offsets maintained by the server for the given topic\partition`

I found a description of the problem [click](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go/issues/891) and the message says that a flag `OffsetOutOfRangeError`  has been added.

But I don't understand how this can help in the solution - it seems to me that restarting the application is equivalent to an error that will be received if `OffsetOutOfRangeError=true`. But if I restart the app, I still get the same errors. How do I fix them?

Comment: from the post i get that the topic got deleted and then created while the app running, would be a problem if you start offset from the beginning ?